# matplotlib check_buttons box colors

Tags: matplotlib

I am using the check_buttons widget like in the example (http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/check_buttons.html)

On a plot with many lines, it is difficult to know from the text which check box goes with which plotted line, at least until the box is clicked and the user looks to see if he can tell which line has disappeared.

Does anyone know if the background color of the check box could be made the same as the line it affects...something like a legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the widget box colour as follows,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s0 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l0, = ax.plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2)
l1, = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2)
l2, = ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
check = CheckButtons(rax, ('2 Hz', '4 Hz', '6 Hz'), (False, True, True))

#Define colours for rectangles and set them
c = ['b', 'g', 'r']    
[rec.set_facecolor(c[i]) for i, rec in enumerate(check.rectangles)]


def func(label):
    if label == '2 Hz': l0.set_visible(not l0.get_visible())
    elif label == '4 Hz': l1.set_visible(not l1.get_visible())
    elif label == '6 Hz': l2.set_visible(not l2.get_visible())
    plt.draw()
check.on_clicked(func)

plt.show()
```

The checkbutton panel has each tick box as a `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` object which can be [customised](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) as needed.

Comment: Yes! Thanks much @Ed Smith. I'm too ashamed to say for how long I have tried to figure this out.

Comment: Glad it worked, widgets for matplotlib are strange, provided mainly for convenience and very limited in what you can change. Just lucky that rectangle is available to change. It's better to go to a full gui framework (e.g. tkinter or wxpython) if you need to do anything but simple customisations.

Comment: I suppose I can't put off for too much longer the move to a gui framework...but thanks to your help, for the nonce I can focus on something else.